# C++ Variable Zero Correction

Tags: c++, visual-c++, double, cout

The variable "probability" always comes out to zero even though the outputs of the other variables are in the same placement area as the probability variable at the end of the program.  I have a feeling it has to do with placement, but it could be another initializing problem.  The probability should never come out to zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int die1, 
        die2, 
        sum,
        turns,
        win=0,
        loss=0;
    double probability=0;
    int thepoint, rolls;
        srand(time(0));


    cout<<"How many turns would you like? ";
    cin>>turns;

    for(int i=0; i<turns; i++)
    {
        sum=0;

        die1=rand()%6;
        die2=rand()%6;
        sum=die1+die2;

        //cout<<"\nFirst die is a  "<<die1<<endl;
        //cout<<"Second die is a "<<die2<<endl;
        //cout<<"\n\n>>>Turn "<<i<<": You rolled "<<sum;


        switch (sum){
            case 2: case 3: case 12:
                //cout<<"You have lost this turn with 2 3 or 12!"<<endl;
                loss++;
                break;
            case 7: 
                //cout<<"\nYea! You won this turn with a 7 on the first roll!"<<endl;

                win++;

                break;      
            case 11:
                //cout<<"You won this turn ith 11!"<<endl;
                win++;
                break;
            default:
                //cout<<"\nRolling again!"<<endl;
                thepoint=sum;
                rolls=1;
                sum=0;
                //cout<<"\nRoll 1 - Your point is "<<thepoint<<endl;
                while (sum != thepoint)
                {
                    //srand(time(0));
                    die1=rand()%6;
                    die2=rand()%6;
                    sum=die1+die2;
                    rolls++;
                    //cout<<"Roll "<<rolls<<". You rolled "<<sum<<endl;
                    if (sum == thepoint)
                    {
                        //cout<<"You won this turn in the while with a point match!"<<endl;
                        win++;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (sum == 7)
                    {
                        loss++;
                        //cout<<"You lost this turn in the while with a 7"<<endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }

    }

    probability = win/turns;

    cout<<"No. of Turns: "<<turns<<"\n";
    cout<<"No. of Wins: "<<win<<"\n";
    cout<<"No. of Loses: "<<loss;

    cout.precision(6);
    cout<<"\nExperimental probability of winning: "<<fixed<<probability;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the variables `win` and `turns` are of datatype `int`, and `probability` is a real number (i.e. double here) you would need to cast at least one of them to `double` before you perform the division.

```
probability = (double)win/turns;
```

BTW, there is no harm in casting both `win` and `turns` too if required but not really needed.

Comment: Casting one is enough, though.

Comment: Yes that is what I mentioned in my answer, I can make it more clear if that is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The `mod 6` operation `% 6` will give you a number in the range 0..5 (the remainder after dividing by 6).  You need to add `1` to that.

change

```
die1=rand()%6;
die2=rand()%6;
```

to

```
die1=1+rand()%6;
die2=1+rand()%6;
```

**Update:** Although this is a bug, it is not the root cause of the probability printing zero, the real problem was pointed out by @Tuxdude.